# custom LowLevelMouseProc callback function not blocking input

Tags: c++, winapi, low-level

I am trying to disable the right mouse click button in windows by hooking the global WH_MOUSE_LL handler which takes care of the following mouse event

WM_RBUTTONDOWN

. Now, i am able to hook the handler with my own custom LowLevelMouseProc callback function, since i am getting expected outfrom to my console. The code is quite small and neat at this current moment and looks like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM 
lParam);

LRESULT CALLBACK myLowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM 
lParam)
{
    if (nCode == 0 && wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        cout << "RBUTTONDOWN intercepted" << endl; // gets outputed whenever i press my right mouse button.
        return -1;

    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int messages()
{
    while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

int main()
{
    hook = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_MOUSE_LL, myLowLevelMouseProc, NULL, 
0);
    return messages();
}
```

The problem here is, that the right mouse click still goes through, and it is not getting blocked. I have tried looking everywhere, and returning non zero "should" block a click, which it does not.

Comment: Why PeekMessage instead of GetMessage?

Comment: Have you tried 'blocking' button up as well ?=

Comment: @darune , i have not tested that no! Got any examples? have never tried it.

Comment: @Anders don't know really. Followed the MSDN documentation and thought it sounded like my fit. It works with it toh, so i dont see any point to change it? Doesn't have anything to do with the problem itself does it? because it is not associated with any block commands

Comment: The problem is not that i don't get any messages to my console, because i do, and that works great, no problem. However, it is my mouse click that doesn't get blocked. So what return value or what should i do in order to block that message inside the callback function?

Comment: check for WM_RBUTTONUP as well

Comment: @darune Thanks, that worked! I did check for that earlier, but i think i did it wrong. Before i checked if(wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN || WM_RBUTTONUP) which made mouse movement blocked and i had to restart xd. Now i did if(wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN || wParam == WM_RBUTTONUP) and it worked. Make a solution so i can give you score.

Comment: Isn't that strange toh. In theory, just blocking WM_RBUTTONDOWN should work? Since right click only fires whenever the down button is released (up) , but the down button can't be released until you press it down first (which should be blocked right there) oh well..

Comment: That is not how it works. The kernel mouse handling is deeper than your hook, the hook just blocks notifications to applications.

Comment: If you do not disable upward messages, theoretically, when you release the right mouse button, you will still send upward messages, which does not conflict with pressing the right mouse button.

Comment: @Anders Gotcha! ty

Answer (score 1):

Problem is fixed when checking for wParam WM_RBUTTONUP along with WM_RBUTTONDOWN

change

```
if (nCode == 0 && wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
```

to:

```
if (nCode == 0 && wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN || wParam == WM_RBUTTONUP)
```